# What's the best way to level my warrior?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In Dragon Age 2, what Attributes and Abilities should I focus on when leveling up my Warrior?

I planned to keep him fighting with two-handed weapons and of course I know strength is important, but are there any things worth knowing, any attributes I can ignore completely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a Warrior you usually fall in to one of two roles, you're either a tank or damage dealer. Since you're wielding two-handed, you should probably be aiming for the damage dealer role (a tank, ideally, would be using a weapon/shield combo for its defensive properties).

As such, for a **damage-dealing Warrior**, your attributes should be considered as such:

**Strenght** is your primary attribute. It increases your damage output and attack rating, it also increases your fortitude score (which makes you harder to knock down, stun, etc). It is a required stat on most Warrior gear. You should maximise this as much as you can.

**Constitution** is your secondary attribute. It increases your health and is a required stat on most Warrior armour. You should ensure it is at least high enough for you to wear the best armour you can currently get your hands on (but probably not much higher).

**Willpower** is also quite important, it increases the quantity of stamina you have available for your abilities. If you keep running out of stamina, pump a few points in to this.

**Dexterity** and **Cunning** are less important, and can be neglected. They increase the frequency and additional damage of critical attacks, but you have abilities that can do the same more effectively (eg, Sunder, which also staggers enemies on criticals). Cunning also increases your defense rating.

For a Warrior, **Magic** only adds a small % of magical resistance - the points are better spent elsewhere.

---

In terms of abilities, you should probably concentrate on the **Two Weapon** and **Vanguard** trees - both of these will help maximise your damage output - and also maybe the **Battlemaster** tree if you need help maintaining your stamina.

And you probably want to look at the **Beserker** and **Reaver** specialisations.

---

Finally, remember that a damage dealing warrior is *not* a Tank, they can and will fall if unsupported when under sustained or heavy attack.

Comment: @atticae No problem, hope it helps. Oh, and I thought I'd said so in the post but it seems I haven't, so please note what I've said here is *entirely irrelevant* to Rogues and Mages, and isn't entirely valid for a tanking Warrior.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the attribute descriptions they will give you a good hint on what to focus on.

Strength for example gives warriors more damage, willpower more stamina to do actions with, etc.

As a physical damage dealer you can pretty much ignore magic. There are other considerations to make as well. If you're low on health and notice you are dying a lot, Constitution will raise your health.

Comment: do you still need dex to help you hit stuff?

Comment: I don't recall the stat screen description of dex off the top of my head, but I'm sure if you checked in game it will be there.

Comment: Hm, played some more and apparently many armors need a certain level of constitution. So this seems to be a good thing to raise as well.

Comment: You don't need dex for to-hit on a warrior; strength increases to-hit for warriors. Magic increases to-hit for mages. Basically, each class has a primary attribute that determines chance to hit and damage dealt.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Strength, don't forget to increase Constitution as well. Lots of good warrior gear has minimum requirements for both Strength and Constitution.